# TikZ matrix is skewed

Tags: tikz-matrix, tikz-calendar

I am trying to create an academic calendar for myself.
I am trying to fill the fall semester in orange color
but the edges of the blocks are *skewed*.
Please help me in positioning the edges either in vertically or horizontally.
I would be happy, if you can help me in simplifying the code if I have some superfluous parts.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calendar}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[column sep=1em, row sep=1em]{
  \calendar (m09) [dates=2018-09-01 to 2018-09-last,week list,month label above centered]; &
  \calendar (m10) [dates=2018-10-01 to 2018-10-last,week list,month label above centered]; &
  \calendar (m11) [dates=2018-11-01 to 2018-11-last,week list,month label above centered]; &
  \calendar (m12) [dates=2018-12-01 to 2018-12-last,week list,month label above centered]; \\
  \calendar (m01) [dates=2019-01-01 to 2019-01-last,week list,month label above centered]; &
  \calendar (m02) [dates=2019-02-01 to 2019-02-last,week list,month label above centered]; &
  \calendar (m03) [dates=2019-03-01 to 2019-03-last,week list,month label above centered]; &
  \calendar (m04) [dates=2019-04-01 to 2019-04-last,week list,month label above centered]; \\
};
\draw[red,thick,fill=orange,opacity=0.5] (m09-2018-09-17.north west) -- (m09-2018-09-23.north east)
  -- (m09-2018-09-30.south east) -- (m09-2018-09-24.south west) -- cycle;
\draw[red,thick,fill=orange,opacity=0.5] (m10-2018-10-01.north west) -- (m10-2018-10-07.north east)
  -- (m10-2018-10-28.south east) -- (m10-2018-10-24.south east) -- (m10-2018-10-31.south east) -- (m10-2018-10-29.south west) -- cycle;
\draw[red,thick,fill=orange,opacity=0.5] (m11-2018-11-05.north west) -- (m11-2018-11-08.north west) -- (m11-2018-11-01.north west)
  -- (m11-2018-11-04.north east) -- (m11-2018-11-25.south east) -- (m11-2018-11-23.south east) -- (m11-2018-11-30.south east)
  -- (m11-2018-11-26.south west)-- cycle;
\draw[red,thick,fill=orange,opacity=0.5] (m12-2018-12-03.north west) -- (m12-2018-12-08.north west) -- (m12-2018-12-01.north west)
  -- (m12-2018-12-02.north east) -- (m12-2018-12-30.south east) -- (m12-2018-12-24.south east) -- (m12-2018-12-31.south east)
  -- (m12-2018-12-31.south west)-- cycle;
\draw[red,thick,fill=orange,opacity=0.5] (m01-2019-01-07.north west) -- (m01-2019-01-08.north west) -- (m01-2019-01-01.north west)
  -- (m01-2019-01-06.north east) -- (m01-2019-01-27.south east) -- (m01-2019-01-24.south east) -- (m01-2019-01-31.south east)
  -- (m01-2019-01-28.south west)-- cycle;
\draw[red,thick,fill=orange,opacity=0.5] (m02-2019-02-01.north west) -- (m02-2019-02-03.north east) -- (m02-2019-02-03.south east)
  -- (m02-2019-02-01.south west)-- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is the `1` narrower than the `31`. Add a `minimum width` to the matrix: `\matrix[column sep=1em, row sep=1em, minimum width=2em]`.

Comment: Is it possible to use 01 instead of 1?

Comment: Yes, it is. The `calendar` library defines some goodies to format the date. See the Ti*k*Z manual for some examples.

Comment: Can we show `M T W R F S ` at top bar as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the first days make a narrower node than the last ones.

The Ti*k*Zy way of doing this would be to require a `minimum width` for the nodes:

```
\matrix[column sep=1em, row sep=1em, minimum width = 2em]{...}
```

this, of course, requires some trial-and-error to get the width right. No one likes that, right?

So browsing the code of `tikzlibrarycalendar.code.tex` I found that the calendar printing routine has some hooks before and after the day. The one that we want here is the `day text` option, which defines some formats for the day (there are equivalents for the month and the year).

The solution that would do (approximately) the same as the `minimum width` option would be:

```
\matrix[column sep=1em, row sep=1em, day text = {\%d=}]{...}
```

This makes the date printed in a constant width box. If you want days less than 10 prepended with a `0`, you can use:

```
\matrix[column sep=1em, row sep=1em, day text = {\%d0}]{...}
```

With either solution, the filled regions are correct:

> [image]

Full code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calendar}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}%                 v---------------v Just added this
\matrix[column sep=1em, row sep=1em, day text = {\%d0}]{
  \calendar (m09) [dates=2018-09-01 to 2018-09-last,week list,month label above centered]; &
  \calendar (m10) [dates=2018-10-01 to 2018-10-last,week list,month label above centered]; &
  \calendar (m11) [dates=2018-11-01 to 2018-11-last,week list,month label above centered]; &
  \calendar (m12) [dates=2018-12-01 to 2018-12-last,week list,month label above centered]; \\
  \calendar (m01) [dates=2019-01-01 to 2019-01-last,week list,month label above centered]; &
  \calendar (m02) [dates=2019-02-01 to 2019-02-last,week list,month label above centered]; &
  \calendar (m03) [dates=2019-03-01 to 2019-03-last,week list,month label above centered]; &
  \calendar (m04) [dates=2019-04-01 to 2019-04-last,week list,month label above centered]; \\
};
\draw[red,thick,fill=orange,opacity=0.5] (m09-2018-09-17.north west) -- (m09-2018-09-23.north east)
  -- (m09-2018-09-30.south east) -- (m09-2018-09-24.south west) -- cycle;
\draw[red,thick,fill=orange,opacity=0.5] (m10-2018-10-01.north west) -- (m10-2018-10-07.north east)
  -- (m10-2018-10-28.south east) -- (m10-2018-10-24.south east) -- (m10-2018-10-31.south east) -- (m10-2018-10-29.south west) -- cycle;
\draw[red,thick,fill=orange,opacity=0.5] (m11-2018-11-05.north west) -- (m11-2018-11-08.north west) -- (m11-2018-11-01.north west)
  -- (m11-2018-11-04.north east) -- (m11-2018-11-25.south east) -- (m11-2018-11-23.south east) -- (m11-2018-11-30.south east)
  -- (m11-2018-11-26.south west)-- cycle;
\draw[red,thick,fill=orange,opacity=0.5] (m12-2018-12-03.north west) -- (m12-2018-12-08.north west) -- (m12-2018-12-01.north west)
  -- (m12-2018-12-02.north east) -- (m12-2018-12-30.south east) -- (m12-2018-12-24.south east) -- (m12-2018-12-31.south east)
  -- (m12-2018-12-31.south west)-- cycle;
\draw[red,thick,fill=orange,opacity=0.5] (m01-2019-01-07.north west) -- (m01-2019-01-08.north west) -- (m01-2019-01-01.north west)
  -- (m01-2019-01-06.north east) -- (m01-2019-01-27.south east) -- (m01-2019-01-24.south east) -- (m01-2019-01-31.south east)
  -- (m01-2019-01-28.south west)-- cycle;
\draw[red,thick,fill=orange,opacity=0.5] (m02-2019-02-01.north west) -- (m02-2019-02-03.north east) -- (m02-2019-02-03.south east)
  -- (m02-2019-02-01.south west)-- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

As Marmot noticed, you are drawing with perpendicular lines, so you can switch from `--` to the `-|` syntax. You can also define some styles to avoid repetition:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calendar}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  calendar fill/.style = {
    red,thick,fill=orange,opacity=0.5
  },
  fullmonth/.style = {
    dates = #1-01 to #1-last
  },
  every calendar/.style = {week list, month label above centered},
]
\matrix[column sep=1em, row sep=1em, day text = {\%d0}]{
  \calendar (m09) [fullmonth = 2018-09]; &
  \calendar (m10) [fullmonth = 2018-10]; &
  \calendar (m11) [fullmonth = 2018-11]; &
  \calendar (m12) [fullmonth = 2018-12]; \\
  \calendar (m01) [fullmonth = 2019-01]; &
  \calendar (m02) [fullmonth = 2019-02]; &
  \calendar (m03) [fullmonth = 2019-03]; &
  \calendar (m04) [fullmonth = 2019-04]; \\
};
\draw[calendar fill] (m09-2018-09-17.north west) -| (m09-2018-09-30.south east) -| cycle;
\draw[calendar fill] (m10-2018-10-01.north west) -| (m10-2018-10-28.south east) -| (m10-2018-10-31.south east) -| cycle;
\draw[calendar fill] (m11-2018-11-05.north west) -| (m11-2018-11-01.north west) -| (m11-2018-11-25.south east) -| (m11-2018-11-30.south east) -| cycle;
\draw[calendar fill] (m12-2018-12-03.north west) -| (m12-2018-12-01.north west) -| (m12-2018-12-30.south east) -| (m12-2018-12-31.south east) -| cycle;
\draw[calendar fill] (m01-2019-01-07.north west) -| (m01-2019-01-01.north west) -| (m01-2019-01-27.south east) -| (m01-2019-01-31.south east) -| cycle;
\draw[calendar fill] (m02-2019-02-01.north west) -| (m02-2019-02-03.south east) -| cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that every other coordinate is redundant (I also noticed that just now) if you switch to the `-|` and `|-` syntax instead of `--`.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Sorry for having the same idea for the `\ContinuedFloat` question! I also have a second approach, if you would undelete your nice answer I can simply remove the part about `\ContinuedFloat` from my answer.

Comment: @marmot Good catch! I updated my answer with these changes. Thanks

Comment: @samcarter No worries, really. If I recall correctly, I also answered a question seconds before you some time ago. We can call it even :)

Answer (score 6):

Here is a rather clumsy way to fix it. The strategy is that, whenever a 1-digit node is used at the left, I mix its coordinate with the x coordinate of a 2-digit node in the same column. E.g. `(m12-2018-12-03.north west)` becomes `(m12-2018-12-03.north -| m12-2018-12-10.west)`.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calendar,backgrounds}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[column sep=1em, row sep=1em]{
  \calendar (m09) [dates=2018-09-01 to 2018-09-last,week list,month label above centered]; &
  \calendar (m10) [dates=2018-10-01 to 2018-10-last,week list,month label above centered]; &
  \calendar (m11) [dates=2018-11-01 to 2018-11-last,week list,month label above centered]; &
  \calendar (m12) [dates=2018-12-01 to 2018-12-last,week list,month label above centered]; \\
  \calendar (m01) [dates=2019-01-01 to 2019-01-last,week list,month label above centered]; &
  \calendar (m02) [dates=2019-02-01 to 2019-02-last,week list,month label above centered]; &
  \calendar (m03) [dates=2019-03-01 to 2019-03-last,week list,month label above centered]; &
  \calendar (m04) [dates=2019-04-01 to 2019-04-last,week list,month label above centered]; \\
};
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
 \draw[red,thick,fill=orange,opacity=0.5] (m09-2018-09-17.north west) -- (m09-2018-09-23.north east)
   -- (m09-2018-09-30.south east) -- (m09-2018-09-24.south west) -- cycle;
 \draw[red,thick,fill=orange,opacity=0.5] (m10-2018-10-01.north -|
 m10-2018-10-29.west) -- (m10-2018-10-07.north east)
   -- (m10-2018-10-28.south east) -- (m10-2018-10-24.south east) -- (m10-2018-10-31.south east) -- (m10-2018-10-29.south west) -- cycle;
 \draw[red,thick,fill=orange,opacity=0.5] (m11-2018-11-05.north -|
 m11-2018-11-26.west) -- (m11-2018-11-08.north west) -- (m11-2018-11-01.north west)
   -- (m11-2018-11-04.north east) -- (m11-2018-11-25.south east) -- (m11-2018-11-23.south east) -- (m11-2018-11-30.south east)
   -- (m11-2018-11-26.south west)-- cycle;
 \draw[red,thick,fill=orange,opacity=0.5] (m12-2018-12-03.north -|
 m12-2018-12-10.west) -- (m12-2018-12-08.north west) -- (m12-2018-12-01.north west)
   -- (m12-2018-12-02.north east) -- (m12-2018-12-30.south east) -- (m12-2018-12-24.south east) -- (m12-2018-12-31.south east)
   -- (m12-2018-12-31.south west)-- cycle;
 \draw[red,thick,fill=orange,opacity=0.5] (m01-2019-01-07.north -|
 m01-2019-01-14.west) -- (m01-2019-01-08.north west) -- (m01-2019-01-01.north west)
   -- (m01-2019-01-06.north east) -- (m01-2019-01-27.south east) -- (m01-2019-01-24.south east) -- (m01-2019-01-31.south east)
   -- (m01-2019-01-28.south west)-- cycle;
 \draw[red,thick,fill=orange,opacity=0.5] (m02-2019-02-01.north west) -- (m02-2019-02-03.north east) -- (m02-2019-02-03.south east)
   -- (m02-2019-02-01.south west)-- cycle;
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

A simpler solution derives from the fact that anyway every other coordinate in your contour is unnecessary. So by making your code shorter you automatically fix the problem.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calendar,backgrounds}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[column sep=1em, row sep=1em]{
  \calendar (m09) [dates=2018-09-01 to 2018-09-last,week list,month label above centered]; &
  \calendar (m10) [dates=2018-10-01 to 2018-10-last,week list,month label above centered]; &
  \calendar (m11) [dates=2018-11-01 to 2018-11-last,week list,month label above centered]; &
  \calendar (m12) [dates=2018-12-01 to 2018-12-last,week list,month label above centered]; \\
  \calendar (m01) [dates=2019-01-01 to 2019-01-last,week list,month label above centered]; &
  \calendar (m02) [dates=2019-02-01 to 2019-02-last,week list,month label above centered]; &
  \calendar (m03) [dates=2019-03-01 to 2019-03-last,week list,month label above centered]; &
  \calendar (m04) [dates=2019-04-01 to 2019-04-last,week list,month label above centered]; \\
};
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
 \draw[red,thick,fill=orange,opacity=0.5] (m09-2018-09-17.north west) -- (m09-2018-09-23.north east)
   -- (m09-2018-09-30.south east) -- (m09-2018-09-24.south west) -- cycle;
 \draw[red,thick,fill=orange,opacity=0.5]  (m10-2018-10-07.north east)
   |- (m10-2018-10-24.south east) |- (m10-2018-10-29.south west) |- cycle;
 \draw[red,thick,fill=orange,opacity=0.5]  (m11-2018-11-08.north west) 
 |- (m11-2018-11-04.north east) |- (m11-2018-11-23.south east) 
 |- (m11-2018-11-26.south west) |- cycle;
 \draw[red,thick,fill=orange,opacity=0.5]  (m12-2018-12-08.north west)
 |- (m12-2018-12-02.north east) |- (m12-2018-12-24.south east) |- (m12-2018-12-31.south west) |- cycle;
 \draw[red,thick,fill=orange,opacity=0.5]  (m01-2019-01-08.north west) 
 |- (m01-2019-01-06.north east) |- (m01-2019-01-24.south east) 
 |- (m01-2019-01-28.south west) |- cycle;
 \draw[red,thick,fill=orange,opacity=0.5] (m02-2019-02-01.north west) -- (m02-2019-02-03.north east) -- (m02-2019-02-03.south east)
   -- (m02-2019-02-01.south west)-- cycle;
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: requires `\end{document}`